# React Swiper Component SlideBy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js

I'm trying to make a time table where users can choose the available times or swipe to it. What I need to do is first show six slides and then let the user click on it or swipe to it.

My code:

```
<Swiper
                        spaceBetween={30}
                        slidesPerView={6}
                        navigation={true}
                        centeredSlides={false}
                    >
                        {this.state.Dates.map(item =>
                            <SwiperSlide>
                                <div className="day_wrapper">
                                    <span className="date">{item.date}</span>
                                    <span className="week_day">{item.dayName}</span>
                                </div>
                            </SwiperSlide>
                        )}
                    </Swiper>
```

The problem is that Swiper doesn't allow me to slide one by one or click on the slides.
This appears to be because it already shows the 6 data available, and cause there is no more data available to show, navigation or clicking is disabled. I am wondering if is there a way to make it slide by one? And clicking the slide too?

Comment: Which React component did you install for Swiper?

Comment: Swiper React, to be clearer a link is provided https://swiperjs.com/react/

Comment: Can you please let me know which style do you want among this demo?https://swiperjs.com/demos/

Comment: Centered Slides, i want user to be able too see other options and easily swipe by them

Comment: I see. Like Thumbs Gallery, there are small list of views and slide by choosing either of one?

Comment: Think about this swiper. https://react-id-swiper.ashernguyen.site/example/thumbs-gallery-with-two-way-control  If we change view instead of image, what do you think?

Comment: not exactly, have you seen when you try to buy Airplane Tickets, and it brings up a slider up there, showing you that u can move the choosen day forward or backward, or pick a date shown in there, i need something exactly like that